# How to add image to result.innerHTML

Tags: javascript

In which format should i enter IMG SRC to a Result in Javascript?

```
var result = document.getElementById('test'); 
result.innerHTML =  price + "img src='catcoin.png'";
```

Comment: Html is composed of tags, so you need to surround your string with < and >: `"<img src='image.png'>"`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest avoiding assigning to innerHTML generally unless it's the only decent option. You can append a new `img` element to a container like this:

```
result.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'catcoin.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('test').src = "catcoin.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.querySelector("#test")
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('src', 'catcoin.png');
el.appendChild(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so don't use text to add elements in JavaScript.

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.src = 'test.png';
```

Then append this new image element to result:

```
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain js:

```js
var price = '$ 04.89';
var test = document.getElementById('test');
while (test.firstChild) {/* optional cleanup, faster than test.innerHTML = '' */
  test.removeChild(test.firstChild);
}
test.appendChild(document.createTextNode(price));
test.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'caticon.png';
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```